# Build Report From Form

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

In `Access 2000` how can I from a command button click, take the data that is on the form and populate a report?

In my thought process I would capture the primary key of the data that is displaying on the form, and that would somehow need to be passed to the report so that the report knows what data to pull from the database to populate.

Just not sure on how to actually do such?

**EDIT**
So I have the data on my form and I added a command button to the form to open the report with the VBA of

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Report1", acPreview, , "empID = " & Me.empID
```

The textboxes on the report are bound to the corresponding database fields, but anytime the report generates it only shows me `#Name?`  And empID is a invisible field on the report that is the primary key, and Me.empID is a field on the form that is the primary key.

Comment: I do not use `Access 2000` never and ever. If you want it in `Access-2007` I can do it.

Comment: @HansUp - Yes, I can do that.

Comment: @HansUp - So go ahead and build out the report and bound the fields, and pass the primary key to the whereCondition of DoCmd.OpenReport?

Comment: Yes, it sounds to me like that should work.  If you run into trouble, update your question with the details.

Comment: The `#Name?` issue is not due to `DoCmd.OpenReport` ... it's a problem in the report design.  Open the report from the Database window and you should see the same thing.